# Add new button to App Component and display a popup window on button click

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, angular, spring-boot

I am new to Angular JS and trying to learn this by developing a simple application.

Currently I have developed a simple app to retrieve and show a master table data, front end (Angular JS) and backend (spring-boot). Further I want to implement CRUDS to this app.

I need your help add a button to app component and onClick a popup window be shown.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very basic question....

I suggest you to go over this tutorial.
https://angular.io/tutorial

And in Angular material you will learn how to work with Dialogs (popups)
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples